# Scripts works fine in CentOS but not on RHEL5

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, rhel

Below script works fine on CentOS but not on RHEL5:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "enter your value:" ip
if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]
then
echo "valid"
else
echo "invalid"
fi
```

Run the script and just pass 192.16666 as input, it will say valid. But if you do the same in CentOS, it will say invalid.

Please let me know what is getting wrong.

Thanks

Comment: On RHEL5 can your check your BASH version?

Comment: Of course, you are definitively absolutely certain you didn't forgot the backslash before the dot (`\.`) on RHEL5... ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself by adding single quotes to the regex, as:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "enter your value:" ip
if [[ $ip =~ '^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$' ]]
   then
     echo "valid"
   else
     echo "invalid"
fi
```

Thanks bdw :)

Answer (score 0):

`=~` matching was [introduced in Bash 3.0-alpha](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges). The [`=~` semantics changed in 3.2](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression), but it seems that was only to force text matching for right-hand quoted strings, which is irrelevant for this case. Is the version older than that?